# Wifi Direct for connecting Android device to PC

Tags: java, android, wifi, p2p

I am developing an android app which needs to communicate with a PC and send data(string) from android device to pc.
I found [P2P](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html) API for android While it is easy to transfer data between two android devices using this technology, but i am not sure how I can do the same between an android device and a PC.
does shareit app use wifi direct?
please guide me how to use wifi direct in pc (using java)

Comment: You haven't a router available in the room with the pc? Just use wifi.

Comment: @greenapps I want to connect android device to pc without router. is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You have two options. Or let thee pc act as hot spot. Or let your Android device act as hot spot.

Comment: @greenapps can you give me sample code or article? Thank you

Comment: For that you dont need any code. Every Android device can act as a hotspot.